# Why is my microbit showing this animation?

Tags: micropython, bbc-microbit

I'm running micropython on a bbc microbit.

My microbit isn't running the program flashed to it, it's displaying
`0, 5, 0, SAD_FACE`

What does that animation mean?

Comment: Have you been able to resolve this issue? I encountered the same issue when I connected it with kittenbot edge connector.

Comment: @ttrs.  Yes as the below answer indiocates it was a problem with the accelerometer.  The number is an error code which you can look up on microbit.org.  You can also generate your own with `microbit.panic(42)`

Comment: So, what did you do with this problem? Did you repair the accelerometer? Or did the error go away by itself?

Comment: Went away itself. I had a program that was hammering `microbit.i2c.scan()` . I repaired that program and it stopped happening

Comment: So, the problem was with the code and not caused by edge connector

Comment: Yes, but i may have caused a bit of damage to the i2c circuits. That program worked without an issue for sometime. I can't remember which microbit it was (i have more than 1) but I'm aware one of them may exhibit i2c issues

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sad face indicates that the microbit has run out of resources or detected a fault. Error code 50 indicates an error with the accelerometer.

This is detailed on the microbit support page at:

https://support.microbit.org/support/solutions/articles/19000016969-micro-bit-error-codes

Comment: I think it must be dying then, because The progam on it wasn't a beast.  I thought it may be power over usb so i connected the edge connector to 3.3v and ground and it stopped